# A set is open if its complement is closed.

Tags: general-topology

I was shown this statement to be a definition.  However, I think that the actual statement would be.

A set is open iff its complement is closed.

This way it's a biconditional and it's also true- this is my proof, with C being a continuum that is nonempty, has no first or last point and has an ordering (<): Suppose $U$ is open.  Let $x$ be a limit point of $C \setminus U$.  It should follow that if $C \setminus U$ is closed, then $x \in (C \setminus U)$.  Now we know that $\forall$ regions $R$ containing $x$, there is a nonempty intersection with $C \setminus U$.  Also, $x$ cannot be a point of the interior of $U$ because any intersection with a region containing it would be empty, which wouldn't be in accordance to our assumption that $x$ is a limit point of $C \setminus U$.  So $x$ is not in the interior of $U$ or $x \notin U$.  This would mean that $x \in (C \setminus U)$ and thus $C \setminus U$ is closed.

I was wondering if this proof was reasonable, if there were any gaps in logic, and if this modification of the definition I presented was viable and justified.

Comment: Does that upvote mean I'm right?

Comment: What I see here is your proposed definition: open iff closed complement, followed by a proof that open only if closed complement. Your proof does establish the latter claim, but you haven't proven that sets with closed complement are always open. I don't see what definition you've modified: your title matches the statement at the beginning of your question.

Comment: OH my mistake, I meant to write if without the two f's on top. Now it should make sense.  Anyway, I just wanted to see if the latter claim was proven, which I am glad it does.  Thank you @KevinCarlson

Comment: Usually _definitions_ are implicitly taken to be biconditional.  So if you have been given the definition of an open set to be a set whose complement is closed, there is no further proof needed.  If, however, you have been given a different definition of an open set, proof may be necessary (for the above stated property of open sets).

Comment: @ArthurFischer  That would have been really helpful to know before I took it upon myself to make it that way.  Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is simply a slightly confusing, but very widespread, convention of mathematical wording.

**In statements, “if” is interpreted just as one direction of implication.**  To specify bidirectional implication, as you say, one needs to write “iff”, or “if and only if”, or “exactly if”, or similar.

**In definitions, however, “if” is used for by-definition equivalence,** which in particular gives the biconditional.  (Quite arguably, it’s exactly the same as a biconditional; logicians can and do split hairs over this issue, but in standard foundations of mathematics, there’s essentially no difference.)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem.